# Does the average web user know about Boolean algebra?

Tags: terminology, users

I am working on a product and it works based on building queries and logical expressions. I am faced with a dilemma to design the product.

1. A simple to understand method without any AND/OR logic, HOWEVER, Some redundancy and overwork for the end-user to create multiple similar items.
2. Another method with super fast output, easy to edit all rules without any redundancy, HOWEVER, it requires AND/OR expressions knowledge.

As boolean expressions look natural to me, I have no idea what percentage of average web users can't/can build and understand a Boolean expression like the following expression:

[image]

More info:

- Target users are web marketers and almost techies, however NOT software engineers
- I understand it is not simple to tell an accurate number about people knowledge, so I would like to know your estimate or a similar experience you may have had.

Comment: Please provide some example. So that the others can help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In *About Face* it is suggested that the average user does not understand boolean logic. That's because in common language *AND* and *OR* have different meaning than they have in boolean algebra.

For example, if I want all users whose age equals 15 or 30, I could say: "give me all users whose age is 15 *and* 30." It's pretty clear to a programmer that that *and* is actually a boolean *or*, but is that clear for the average user?

Same goes for *or*, which can be used as a boolean *XOR*.

Comment: Your example is beautiful.

Comment: Does that mismatch hold for ranges? "15 .. 30"  / "between 15 and 30" / >15 and <30  / even ">=15 and <=30"

Comment: @rogerovo: nice question. The article linked by PhillipW might shed some light on that.

Answer (score 2):

There's rather a lot in this article - and it's rather heavy going psychology: but the bottom line is that most people are rather rubbish at formal logic and deductive and inductive thinking:

It's based on experiments called the 'Wason Verification Task'

http://www.psychologyinaction.org/2012/10/07/classic-psychology-experiments-wason-selection-task-part-i/

Comment: The article was interesting, however it is difficult to relate it to the topic.

Comment: Yes its quite heavy going: however it covers experimental evidence that people aren't good at 'formal logic' which of course is what boolean is all about.